# D3 js legend for a dynamic dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was wondering how can I add a d3 js legend for a dataset, which does not have the same amount of objects every time and how to avoid assigning the different colors, without explicitly having them in the dataset.

An example of what I have is:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(tasks)
  .enter()
  .append("g")

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", function(d){return d.color})
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("x", -100)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){return 20+20*i})

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("y", function(d, i){return 32+20*i})
  .attr("x", -90)
  .text(function (d) {
       return d.taskName
  });
```

In this example, the color is contained in the dataset, which I am trying to avoid. Moreover, if the dataset consists of significantly more elements, the legend will either overflow or overlap the chart.

I also saw `d3-legend.js`, which I could not end up getting to work, however, I was thinking the color issue may be avoided by creating a color domain, but I am relatively new to d3.js and could not do it. As for the overlap/overflow, I am clueless.

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1L3jmge/38/) to the above example.

Comment: To move the color data out of the observations, just store an object that maps something like {key: color, key2: color2}, where key is an attribute you're already storing in your data. Then inside your `.attr("fill", function(d){return d.color})` you'd do `.attr("fill", function(d){return colorMap[d.attr]})`

Comment: But for the object, I would still need to know the items in the dataset. In the example from the jsfiddle, there are 5 jobs, if the dataset changes to 10 jobs, I would not have colors for the rest of the jobs.

Comment: just loop over your data once and count the number of distinct colors you need (based on some attribute of your data elements), then you can create just the right amount of colors.

Comment: Is this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `colorScale` by interpolating `n` times (the length of your dataset) throughout a range between two predetermined colours.

```
const colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([1, data.length])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)
  .range([d3.rgb(colorA), d3.rgb(colorB)])
```

You can access a color from within the scale, both when creating each data element and each legend element in the exact same way (ensuring identical colors)

```
colorScale(i)
```

As for designing the legend in a way that minimises overlap/overflow, the layout can be done with either CSS flexbox, columns, float (choose your favourite).

---

Full solution:

```js
var data = [{
  "first_name": "Daisey"
}, {
  "first_name": "Lowell"
}, {
  "first_name": "Evaleen"
}, {
  "first_name": "Reube"
}, {
  "first_name": "Barnebas"
}, {
  "first_name": "Raddie"
}, {
  "first_name": "Caitlin"
}, {
  "first_name": "Jorry"
}, {
  "first_name": "Ruth"
}, {
  "first_name": "Aldrich"
}]

const legend = d3.select("#legend")
const colorA = "#0000FF"
const colorB = "#7FFF00"

const colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, data.length])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)
  .range([d3.rgb(colorA), d3.rgb(colorB)]);


const legendItem = legend.selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'legend-item')


legendItem.append('div').attr('class', 'legend-item--color').style('background-color', (d, i) => colorScale(i))

legendItem.append('h3')
  .attr('class', 'legend-item--header')
  .text(d => d.first_name)
```

```css
#legend {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.legend-item {
  flex: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.legend-item--header {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.legend-item--color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="legend"></div>
```

[Example block](http://bl.ocks.org/jfreyre/b1882159636cc9e1283a)

---

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k_sav/oa703n4j/)